# This command should print all the matching cases from two table but it is printing only 1st matching case. need a little alteration only

Tags: mysql

It should print the whole list from two joined tables of students  ordered by course name that is cname.

```
select cname, room, count(snum) as no_of_students
 from class left outer join enrolled 
 on enrolled.cname = class.cname 
 group by cname
 order by no_of_students desc;
```

I tried this command but here it is showing cname is ambiguous but i don't understand why? can anyone explain.

Comment: _cname is ambiguous_ means that the same field name is in both tables and you need to specify from what table to take it.

Answer (score 0):

you shold add selected columns not involved in aggregation function at the group by clause

```
select class.cname
    , room
    , count(snum) as no_of_students
from class 
left  join enrolled on enrolled.cname = class.cname 
group by cname, room 
order by no_of_students desc;
```

otherwise if you are using mysql version < 5.7 you have unpredictable result  and with mysql version >= 5.7  by default  this produce an error

anyway if you have anbigous column anem you need  full qualified  column name

Comment: no by adding room to group by it will just take care  of room but not solve ambiguity  of cname. and i think i found my answer. thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @HimanshuKaushik  answer updated for ambiguity  ..  too

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is not able to distinguish between two cname from two tables i think that's why by specifying  class.cname it worked fine. still if i am thinking it wrong pleass correct me.

Comment: You must use the column from the *left* table `class.cname` in the group by clause and the select list.